# Is WAMP publish/subscribe battery efficient?

Tags: api, rest, publish-subscribe, wamp-protocol

I am writing an client side desktop app that will need to receive updates from a server. These updates would be few and far between (possibly 1 a week) but I would like them to be received as quickly as possible.

Is it hard on the battery to "subscribe" to the topic that will provide the updates through `WAMP` and let the app run in the background continuously? Would it be more efficient to periodically poll the server using a REST based API?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP requires a persistent connection - so you have to deal with the battery drain for this. The only way to find out how much of a cost this is is to test it on the system you'll be running the app on. Then you can consider the actual trade offs involved versus a polling solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are no implications on energy consumption when subscribing. However there are implications when persisting a connection for so long time for so few updates. You should reconsider your use of WAMP as your communication protocol I think.